# How do I get my HDD in my in my freshly installed Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-disk, ssd, gparted

I have a SSD and a HDD on my system. I had wiped my SSD and installed ubuntu a few days before. My HDD had three partitions at the time. Their names were GApps, TMV, and study.
But ubuntu only detected GApps at the time so I reinstalled Windows 10 on my system. Since then, I've tried many distros but still, the problem was still the same but I am using a pendrive for the boot since i don't want to wipe out my SSD again until i am sure of it.

---

Now, I've deleted the partition(GApps) and formed a new partition. But still, while I view it from ubuntu, I can still see its name and its previous size(200gb).
When I view the same from Gparted, it shows that GApps's size is of 930GB which is my total hard drive.
[This is the terminal when i type lsblk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzhFg.png)
[This is the terminal when I type sudo fdisk -l](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEbzY.png)
[This is my Gparted Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBLJg.png)

Comment: Are you talking about the system disk or other (perhaps external) drive? Also please add `lsblk` and `fdisk -l` outputs to the question.

Comment: it looks like you have used "default" method of drive partitioning while you have installed your distro. It uses the whole drive (you drive is 1 tb, isn't it?). so, most probably your other partitions were deleted.

Comment: Well, I have two disks in my laptop. I have edited the question. @VojtechTrefny

Comment: LDM data is Microsoft proprietary dynamic partitions. How did you get that? Not required with gpt as dynamic was a Microsoft work around for the 4 primary MBR partition limit. Microsoft has no undo, suggests backup, delete & reformat. Some third party Windows tools may convert in place, but have really good backup. https://askubuntu.com/questions/482768/changing-windows-dynamic-disk-partition-to-basic-partition-and-not-the-full-driv Best to undo dynamic, but there is this: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/ldmtool.1.html